# Ros not responding to keypress to WaitKey

Tags: ros, c++, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys..

I am using openCV to run some video processing, in which i switch 2 algorithm, and the switch is performed by the user, from a key press.. The only problem is though i am not able it make react on key press.

It seems like it keep looping around the same code, even though i press a key..

How do i make it change??

Here is the code..

Main.cpp

```
#include "class.cpp"


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
   ros::init(argc, argv, "image_converter");
   ImageConverter ic;
   ros::spin();
   return 0;
}
```

class.h

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "sensor_msgs/JointState.h"
#include "facedetect.h"
#include <cmath>



using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static const std::string OPENCV_WINDOW = "Image window";


class ImageConverter
{
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
  image_transport::Subscriber image_sub_;
  image_transport::Publisher image_pub_;
  std::vector<double> pos;
  std::vector<double> vel;
  double position_prev_p;
  double position_prev_t;
  pair<double,double> displacement;
  ros::Subscriber sub;
  ros::Publisher facedetect_pub;
  Rect face;
  bool state;
  

public:
      void chatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr& msg);
      ImageConverter();
      ~ImageConverter();
      void imageDetect(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg);


};
```

class.cpp

```
#include "class.h"

ImageConverter::ImageConverter()
    : it_(nh_),pos(2),  vel(2) 
  {
    // Subscrive to input video feed and publish output video feed
    
        image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/custom/left/image_rect_color", 1, 
        &ImageConverter::imageDetect, this);
        image_pub_ = it_.advertise("/image_converter/output_video", 1);
        state = false;
  }

 

    ImageConverter::~ImageConverter()
      {
        //cv::destroyAllWindows();
      }
      
      void ImageConverter::imageDetect(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
      {
         facedetect_pub = nh_.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("/custom/cmd", 1);
         sub = nh_.subscribe("/joint_states",1,&ImageConverter::chatterCallback,this); 
         cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
         sensor_msgs::JointState ms;
        try
        {
          cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
        }
        catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
        {
          ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
          return;
        }
    
        if (!state) {
            cout <<"Can i see you ?" << endl;
    
            if(waitKey(10) != 'y')
            {
                face = detectAndDisplay(cv_ptr->image);
            }else{
                state = true;
            }
        }else{
            cout <<"Face detected" << endl; 
            displacement = track(face,cv_ptr->image);
            if(abs(pos[0]-position_prev_p) < 0.50 )
            {
                pos[0] = ceil(sin(displacement.first*0.000727220522)*1000)/1000 + position_prev_p;
            }
            if(abs(pos[1]-position_prev_t) < 0.50)
            {
                cout << "tilt change" << endl;
                pos[1] = -ceil(sin(displacement.second*0.000727220522)*1000)/1000 + position_prev_t;
            }
            
                ms.position = pos;
                vel[0] =0;
                vel[1] = 0;
                ms.velocity = vel;
                ROS_INFO_STREAM("pan: "<<pos[0]);
                ROS_INFO_STREAM("pan_prev: " << position_prev_p);
                ROS_INFO_STREAM("Subtracted: " <<abs(pos[0]-position_prev_p));
                ROS_INFO_STREAM("tilt: "<<pos[1]);
                ROS_INFO_STREAM("tilt_prev: " << position_prev_t);
                ROS_INFO_STREAM("Subtracted: " <<abs(pos[1]-position_prev_t));
                facedetect_pub.publish(ms);
                ROS_WARN_STREAM("OUT of if");
        
        }
    
    }
    
    void ImageConverter::chatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr& msg)
       {    
         position_prev_p = (msg->position[0]);
         position_prev_t = (msg->position[1]);
       }
```

facedetect.h - detectAndDisplay

```
Rect detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )
{
        vector<Rect> faces(1);
        Point center_of_frame(frame.size().width/2,frame.size().height/2);
        pair<Point, Point> corners;
        pair<double,double> displacement;
        double displacement_pixel_x;
        double displacement_pixel_y;
        bool foundFace = false;
        pair<Rect, bool> response;
                if (frame.type()!= 8) {
                        cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_8U);
                }
   
        //-- 1. Load the cascades
                if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_XML ) ){
                        cout << "Cascade Error" << endl;
                };
   
                circle(frame, center_of_frame, 1, CV_RGB(0,255,255),8,8,0);
   
        //-- Detect faces
                face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame, faces, 1.1, 2, 0, Size(100, 100) );
                       
                        for( int i = 0; i<faces.size() ; i++)
                        {
                                Point center_position_of_face((faces[i].br().x+faces[i].tl().x)/2,(faces[i].tl().y+faces[i].br().y)/2);
                                Point corner_1(faces[i].br().x,faces[i].tl().y);
                                Point corner_2 = faces[i].tl();
                                Point corner_3 = faces[i].br();
                                Point corner_4(faces[i].tl().x,faces[i].br().y);
                                rectangle(frame, faces[i], CV_RGB(0,255,0),4,8,0);
                                circle(frame, center_position_of_face, 8, CV_RGB(128,128,128),8,8,0);
                                circle(frame, corner_1, 1, CV_RGB(128,128,128),8,8,0);
                                circle(frame, corner_2, 1, CV_RGB(128,128,128),8,8,0);
                                circle(frame, corner_3, 1, CV_RGB(128,128,128),8,8,0);
                                circle(frame, corner_4, 1, CV_RGB(128,128,128),8,8,0);
                                line(frame, center_position_of_face, center_of_frame, CV_RGB(0,200,0),1,8);
                                //displacement_pixel_x = (center_position_of_face.x-center_of_frame.x);
                                //displacement_pixel_y = (center_position_of_face.y-center_of_frame.y);
 
                        }
       
                flip(frame, frame, 1);
                imshow("Facedetection", frame);
               
                if(waitKey(1000) != 'y')
                return faces.back();
 
}
```

It keeps outputting "can i see you?" i it looks like it keeps looping the same statement, again and again.. how do i fix it..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205863/ros-not-responding-to-keypress-to-waitkey../) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I choose to remove the `waitKey(1) != 'y`' solution and use this one instead

http://answers.ros.org/question/63491/keyboard-key-pressed/

---

Originally posted by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) with karma: 156 on 2015-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The waitKey only detects keypresses from an opencv highgui window in focus.  Add an imshow of nothing at all or some interesting visualization, click on it and then you should be able to type.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey

> The function only works if there is
> at least one HighGUI window created
> and the window is active. If there are
> several HighGUI windows, any of them
> can be active.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-03-25**:
detectAndDisplay() does open a imshow window.. i could try to open a empty outside of the function, if thats what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You just wait for 10 miliseconds for a key input on every image.

```
if(waitKey(10) != 'y')
{
      face = detectAndDisplay(cv_ptr->image);
}
```

I don't think that's enough time for you to press the key in the right moment ;)

Wait some more to be able to press the right key, if that's not an option you may want to think about a design change (maybe put the image display in an extra thread).

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [Malefitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19412/malefitz/) with karma: 136 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-03-26**:
We'll if i Increase the time, will make the image flow slower..

**Comment by [Malefitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19412/malefitz/) on 2015-03-26**:
Well if that's the case as I said you probably have to put the code for showing the image and recognizing the key input into an extra thread.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-03-26**:
How would you make multiple threads in ROS.. If my main keeps spinning my constructor.. ?

**Comment by [Malefitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19412/malefitz/) on 2015-03-26**:
If you use a boost thread just for showing the image and listening to the key input it shouldn't interfer with ros. Something similar to this should work:

```
//ownThreadLoop()
while(1)
{
imshow(imgPtr)
if(waitkey(10) == 'y')
state = true
}
```

You may need a mutex for the image.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-03-31**:
What about using a an extra node, which signals the first node?..
too much ?

**Comment by [Malefitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19412/malefitz/) on 2015-04-01**:
That's a bit overkill. Did you try it the way I suggested and it didn't work? With boost threads?

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-04-01**:
Well.. it was more avoid using multiple threads and so on..

I am bit unsure on where you want it running, The image pointer is only accessible from within the class itself, so the only way i can do as you suggest is within the class, but as far as i Know multithreading within a class..

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-04-01**:
Added  `detectAndDisplay(Mat)` function from the h. file facedetect.h.

To help you guys to understand the situation.. All support is appreciated :)